# How do I print multiple json arrays

Tags: html, arrays, json, laravel

I am looping through a database using an array as follows

```
$checkedProducts = $request->input('products');
$p = null;

foreach($checkedProducts as $checkedProduct){
    $p .= DB::table('products')->where('id', $checkedProduct)->get();
}
dd($p);
```

This is the output.

```
[{"id":"6","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"df","slug":"fgh","details":"hgfh","description":"gf","image":"\/storage\/RZbE9tqTPL3boEVztOfjR1P7IgFeX0OpMMzr21rO.jpeg","sku":"hjhg","price":"456","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"67","out_of_stock":"56","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14"}][{"id":"7","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"erty","slug":"bvn","details":"fghj","description":"ghj","image":"\/storage\/J4w9kf06vkCRx4c6S7BvBHV2TA1tYrZuv1sUG5KQ.jpeg","sku":"hj","price":"23","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"45","out_of_stock":"45","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32"}][{"id":"8","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"werty","slug":"thyju","details":"red","description":"ytyu","image":"\/storage\/Wj09GjAkmlbk2GZHwVeaJLRLkJE83gryYAsUdvna.jpeg","sku":"dwg","price":"2345","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"5000","out_of_stock":"50","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06","updated_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06"}]
```

How do I print this out in the blade file? I have tried forEach loop but it's not working

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Your JSON is not a valid array but several arrays - you need the server to produce valid JSON or you need to split

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. You need to manipulate it to get the data into a proper object:

```js
const str = `[{"id":"6","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"df","slug":"fgh","details":"hgfh","description":"gf","image":"\/storage\/RZbE9tqTPL3boEVztOfjR1P7IgFeX0OpMMzr21rO.jpeg","sku":"hjhg","price":"456","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"67","out_of_stock":"56","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14"}][{"id":"7","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"erty","slug":"bvn","details":"fghj","description":"ghj","image":"\/storage\/J4w9kf06vkCRx4c6S7BvBHV2TA1tYrZuv1sUG5KQ.jpeg","sku":"hj","price":"23","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"45","out_of_stock":"45","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32"}][{"id":"8","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"werty","slug":"thyju","details":"red","description":"ytyu","image":"\/storage\/Wj09GjAkmlbk2GZHwVeaJLRLkJE83gryYAsUdvna.jpeg","sku":"dwg","price":"2345","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"5000","out_of_stock":"50","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06","updated_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06"}]`

const dl = document.getElementById("dl");

let dlContent = [];
JSON.parse("[" + str.split("][").join("],[") + "]").forEach((arr, i) => {
  dlContent.push(`<dt><h3>item ${i}</h3></dd>`);
  Object.entries(arr[0]).forEach(([k, v]) => dlContent.push(`<dt>${k}</dt><dd>${v}</dd>`))
})
dl.innerHTML = dlContent.join("")
```

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 10em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<dl id="dl"></dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make JSON valid on source

check [json documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) it's simple rules for valid JSON

in your case you have `array1array2array3` put them in another array `[array1,array2,array3]` comma separated

2. than you can easily print them out

```js
const arrays = [
[{"id":"6","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"df","slug":"fgh","details":"hgfh","description":"gf","image":"\/storage\/RZbE9tqTPL3boEVztOfjR1P7IgFeX0OpMMzr21rO.jpeg","sku":"hjhg","price":"456","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"67","out_of_stock":"56","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:14"}],
[{"id":"7","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"erty","slug":"bvn","details":"fghj","description":"ghj","image":"\/storage\/J4w9kf06vkCRx4c6S7BvBHV2TA1tYrZuv1sUG5KQ.jpeg","sku":"hj","price":"23","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"45","out_of_stock":"45","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32","updated_at":"2020-06-01 11:15:32"}],
[{"id":"8","category_id":"1","shop_id":"31","name":"werty","slug":"thyju","details":"red","description":"ytyu","image":"\/storage\/Wj09GjAkmlbk2GZHwVeaJLRLkJE83gryYAsUdvna.jpeg","sku":"dwg","price":"2345","minimum_order_quantity":"0","stock":"5000","out_of_stock":"50","featured":"1","created_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06","updated_at":"2020-06-02 08:32:06"}]
];

arrays.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```